# How does one bind a method to a name in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, syntax, anonymous-function

In Kotlin, the code snippet `val f = println()` binds the function `println` (which is a first class object) to the name `f`.

> How do I do the same with the method [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html), i.e. store it in `f`?

The syntax `val f = map` does not work, neither does `val f = arrayOf(1,2,3).map`. I have tried various variations of the above, with no success.

Also (and related), why does `val f = println` not work, making the brackets necessary? I come from the functional programming camp (Scheme), where this would be absolutely normal.

(Disclaimer: absolute Kotlin novice, trying to learn it by myself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Kotlin, the code snippet `val f = println()` binds the function `println` (which is a first class object) to the name `f`.

Not true. This assigns the return value result of calling `println()`, which is `Unit`, to the variable `f`. To get a function reference, use `::`. But you must also specify the variable type, because it cannot be inferred when the function has overloads:

```
val f: (Any)->Unit = ::println
```

A function with a receiver should be specified using the receiving type, like

```
val f = Any::toString

// or, to bind a specific instance's toString:
val myList = listOf("Hello", "World")
val myListToString = myList::toString
```

Since `map` is a higher-order function, it has a long and complicated signature:

```
val f: Array<Int>.((Int)->String)->List<String> = Array<Int>::map
```